# QT Creating clone item of scaled graphic item

Tags: c++, qt, scale, qgraphicsitem

I craeted my own class (inheriting from QGraphicsItem) and added handlers for mouse events - now i can move it around, drop it in new place etc. Also I added scaling functions:

```
void scaleUp()
{
    scale(ScaleFactor_X,ScaleFactor_Y);
}

void scaleDown()
{
    scale(1/ScaleFactor_X,1/ScaleFactor_Y);
}
```

Where ScaleFactor_X and ScaleFactor_Y are class's parameters.

Also, I added "shadow" feature - whenever I start dragging object arround, copy of given object stay in current position until I drop orginal object in new place.

```
CustomObject::CustomObject(bool isNumerable, int _x, int _y, int _w, int _h) 
{
   X=_x;
   Y=_y;
   Widith = _w;
   Height = _h;
}
```

Problem is - whenever I scale object object up/down - i can't realy update Widith and Height parametrs that i use to create copy and so - my copy is always useing default values.

I tried modifing my scaleing functions like that:

```
void scaleUp()
{
        Height = ScaleFactor_Y *Height;
        Widith = ScaleFactor_X *Widith;
        update();
}
```

but that caused my clone to 1) have propper shape (Height and Widith) but was always moved, a bit to some simingly random dirrection.

I do not know how could i correct scaleign with my widith and height to still be able to create my clone.